# Retrieve a number in a webpage and store in a SQLite3 db

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, regex, sqlite

I'm beggining Python. So I wrote a program which is supposed to get a number of connected people on a forum (like this one : http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-51-0-1-0-1-0-blabla-18-25-ans.htm) and store the number with the datetime in a database file (SQLite3). Every forum has his own table name.

My code is supposed to do this :

> 1. Create object for each forum we want to retrieve with the Forum class.
> 2. Store these objects in a list to put use in a loop For.
> 3. Get a web page .htm (with requests) where the number of connected people is wrote in a span tag with the class "nb-connect-fofo" who looks like this `<span class="nb-connect-fofo">1799 connecté(s)</span>`. I'm using BeautifulSoup to get the string and REGEX to get the number  It's supposed to be done for every forum
> 4. Execute a SQLite3 request to store the datetime, number in database file with the same name as the forum which is retrieve

Here's my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import sqlite3
import datetime
import requests
import re



class Forum:

    def __init__(self, forum, url_forum): #initialization all object with there name, URL
        self.forum = forum
        self.url_forum = url_forum

        pattern = '([0-9]{1,5})'
        self.pattern = re.compile(pattern)

    def add_to_database(self): #Add to the SQLite3 database the number of connected people and the datetime to their own table
        connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        c = connection.cursor()
        now = datetime.datetime.today()
        nb_co = self.recup_co()

        text = "INSERT INTO {0}(datetime, nb_co) VALUES('{1}', '{2}')".format(self.forum, now, nb_co)
        c.execute(text)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

        print(now, self.forum, str(nb_co))
        sleep(1)

    def recup_co(self): #Retrieving the page and the number of people connected by using REGEX
        r = requests.get(self.url_forum)
        page_html = str(r.text)
        page = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser') 
        resultat = page.select(".nb-connect-fofo")

        nb_co = re.search(self.pattern, str(resultat))

        return nb_co.group(0)

def main(): 
    # All forums which are scanned are here
    dixhuit_vingtcinq = Forum("dixhuit_vingtcinq", "http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-51-0-1-0-1-0-blabla-18-25-ans.htm")
    moins_quinze = Forum("moins_quinze", "http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-15-0-1-0-1-0-blabla-moins-de-15-ans.htm")
    quinze_dixhuit = Forum("quinze_dixhuit", "http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-50-0-1-0-1-0-blabla-15-18-ans.htm")
    overwatch = Forum("overwatch", "http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-33972-0-1-0-1-0-overwatch.htm")

    #All forum name's are stored here to use them with a list
    forums = [dixhuit_vingtcinq, moins_quinze, quinze_dixhuit, overwatch] 

    while(True):
        for forum in forums:
            try:
                forum.add_to_database()
            except:
                print("An error occured with the forum '{0}' at {1}".format(forum.forum, datetime.datetime.today()))
                sleep(5)
        sleep(60)

main()
```

I will use it later to make graphics, make little statistics to improve my skill with Python. Maybe I will retrieve more forum and expand my program to scrap the website and get every post on these forums (If I, I will do this in a lot of time later).

*So I'm asking you for some improvements/ideas. As a beginner, there are obviously somes errors that can be very annoying. Because, i really want to improve*

Also, my code is running on one of my own server. Isn't it better to buy a cheap VPS for 2€ instead ?

Thanks for reading and thanking you in advance.

PS : If there are somes mistakes relatives to my post about the website tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Code smells

- your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because *you are using string formatting to put query parameters into a query*. You need to proper parameterize your query with the help of the database driver:

  ```
  query = """
      INSERT INTO {table} (datetime, nb_co)
      VALUES(?, ?)
  """.format(table=self.forum)
  c.execute(query, (now, nb_co))
  ```

  Note that this way you also don't need to worry about Python to database type conversions and quotes inside parameters - it will all be handled by the database driver.

#### Performance

- instead of re-connecting to the database multiple times, think about connecting to a database once, processing all the data and then closing the connection afterwards
- same idea about the use of `requests` - you may [initialize a `Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and reuse
- use `lxml` instead of `html.parser` as an [underlying parser used by `BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)
- you can use [`SoupStrainer` class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to parse only the desired element, which will allow you to then simply get the text and split by space instead of applying a regular expression:

  ```
  parse_only = SoupStrainer(class_="nb-connect-fofo")
  page = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)
  return page.get_text().split()[0]
  ```